# directx 10 shadowing weirdness

Tags: directx, shadow

I'm getting some really weird shadowing on this directx 10 sdkmesh model.

http://jacobsgriffith.com/directx10/weirdshadows.png

Where do I look in my code to fix this issue, is it an issue with the mesh normals?? The mesh polygons seem to be intact so I'm not sure

If you would like to download the source code I'm using the same as this book 3D Game Programming using directx 10 and OpenGl and the source is here Chapter 17.

http://cws.cengage.co.uk/rautenbach/students/code.htm

Comment: it could be your normals, or any of the shader maths that operate on the normals. But the fact that your shading looks ok on the model suggests that maybe the normals are ok. Try changing your shader to output only the normals (or other lighting terms) and visually debug it